# How do I get the value of multiple IDs in a Laravel API request

Tags: laravel-5

I have Laravel acting as an API serving a request from an Emberjs app.

The app requests multiple ID's

```
vipExperiences?ids=6&ids=4
```

In my Laravel controller, `$request->input('ids')` returns just the last ID (i.e. 4) where I would expect an array or something with both.

How do I best get it to return multiple ID's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **If you are able to modify the query strings, add brackets to the names**

   Simply change your query strings to look like `vipExperiences?ids[]=6&ids[]=4` then when you call `$request->input('ids')` you'll get the array you are looking for.
2. **If you can't edit it you should be able to do something like this**

   ```
   $url = explode('?', $request->fullUrl());
   $querystrings = explode('&', $url[1]);

   foreach ($querystrings as $param) {
      list($name, $value) = explode('=', $param, 2);
      $params[urldecode($name)][] = urldecode($value);
   }
   // dd($params);
   ```